# Having a lot of trouble not uselessly accessing my DB

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();

include '../dbconnect_form_fields.php';

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_fields") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<form id='list' action='form_calc.php' method='post'>
<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr><td><select>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td><select>";

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_fields") or die(mysql_error());

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){ 
    echo "<option value='".$row1['id']."'>".$row1['field']." ".$row1['price']."</option>";
}
?>
```

For some reason, when i change that line that says $res1 = mysql_query blah blah blah, It doesnt seem to work, the select field is empty with no options. It seems as though I would have to define $res as a mysql_fetch and for a second select box, access the DB a second time but using a different variable...

How can I make the $res variable carry across the loops without having to access the DB so many times... I play to have six of these loops... Help me gurus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to clarify what your intentions are. From your code you are creating two of the same select elements. If you want to output the same select element twice, you could try

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_fields") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<form id='list' action='form_calc.php' method='post'>
<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr>
<?php for($i=0;$i<1;$i++) { //Loop twice to create a second select element ?>
    <td><select>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>
</td>
<?php } //End of for loop ?>
</tr>
```

Alternatively, you could just copy/paste the same while loop twice without changing any variables

```
<form id='list' action='form_calc.php' method='post'>
<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr>
    <td><select>
        <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><select>
        <?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['field']." ".$row['price']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey ben thnx for the help there... I tried your first bit of code and, well... See for yourself. It almost exactly as you pasted it (minus a few syntax errors :)) www.oriondesignmtl.com/forms/form1.php